# IOS, ASWebAuthSession, SSO, Cordova, OAuth app multiple login requiring to enter credentials

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, single-sign-on

Im trying to use a 3rd party enterprise OAuth2 provider for my IOS Ionic v1 app to login.

Since upgrading to WKWebview the inapp-browser based login is not working anymore

Currently using ASWebAuthSession from IOS and cordova plugin available for it cordova-plugin-ios-aswebauthenticationsession

```
    var loginUrl = 'https://mywebsite/_oauth/login?app_name=mytestapp&redirect_url=https://mywebsite/_oauth/login/mobile-app/iosredirect.html';

    window.plugins.ASWebAuthSession.start("mytestapp://", loginUrl,
    function(msg){
      console.log("Success ", msg);
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("Error " + msg);
    });
```

For the first time App launch > Login > new window opens and loads 3rd party  login screen > on username and password enter > success > closes window > I get the access_token in Success callback. All good for first time

But second time it goes through same flow as first time. With ASWebAuthSession API is it not supposed to remember the cookie and pass to the OAuth provider and return to app? Should not ASWebAuthSession work wrt SSO?

Ive also tried the now deprecated SFAuthenticationSession, but with no luck.

Further to prove that ASWebAuthSession shares data from Safari in IOS I tried this:

In safari browser logged into facebook, and in my app started an instance of ASWebAuthSession as below, directly loaded my facebook feeds without asking for re-login.

```
      window.plugins.ASWebAuthSession.start("mytestapp://", 'http://www.facebook.com',
      function(msg){
        console.log("Success ", msg);
      }, function (err) {
          console.log("Error " + msg);
      });
```

Why is not my OAuth behaving same. SSO works well on browser

Any help much Appreciated. Thanks

```
Details and Versions:

   @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.0.1

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim           : 8.0.1 
    Node              : v10.16.0
    npm               : 6.9.0 
    OS                : macOS
    Xcode             : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

Comment: Does the login page that you open know that it should check whether the user is already logged in? I suspect that the reason Facebook works is because Facebook knows to check whether there is a user session in the browser already. If your login page isn't doing that then ASWebAuthSession won't know to return the user session on its own automatically.

Comment: Yes, in browser the login page looks if user has already logged in does not  asks for login again, also in android app (in-app browser approach) works well. thanks for the reply